# Caculated Column IF statement

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Having a hard time finding this question already answered somewhere, so here it is.

I am trying to create a calculated column that returns the following result.

- If "column 1" equals *"OPEN"*, then enter "column 2" + 3
- If "column 1" equals *"PENDING"*, then return "Blank"

Column 1 is a dropdown list.  Column 2 is a date.

I need the calculated column to return the date in column 2 adding three days, only if column 1 states "OPEN."

If column 1 states anything else, I need column 2 to be blank.

Any assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculated column "column 3" cannot change the value of "column 2".

You can display "column 3" and hide "column 2" in list view and DisForm.aspx, and display "column 2" in NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx (the calculated column will not display in NewForm.aspx and EditForm.aspx ).

Using the following formula in "column 3":

```
=IF([column 1]="OPEN", [column 2]+3, "")
```

[image]

Testing result of calculated formula:

[image]

Comment: That is just what I was looking for. Works perfectly.  Thanks so much

Comment: @Ulcsmarine001 Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!!